# Pass pointer to itself in emit() in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, signals-slots

I have a class handling file transfers.
One of the emits is a `finished()` signal

on the parent side, I'd like to connect this `finished()` signal to a `fileTransferFinished()` Slot
But how can I know which instance is finished? as there are plenty of them running at the same time..

I know I can make use of the `QObject::sender()` method to return  the emitter, but this way, I can't acces a method of my instance..

> qDebug() << "finished " << QObject::sender()->getID();

it says `no member named getID in QObject`

I'd like to have my pointer inside the Slot function, is that possible?

Comment: Why don't you just add a parameter to the signal/slot to indicate the finished one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the prototype of `Object::sender()` in the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#sender):

```
QObject * QObject::sender() const
```

It returns a pointer to QObject instance, hence you will not be able to call `getID()` method on that return value.

Cast the return value of `Object::sender()` to pointer of your class before using it :

```
YourClass * sender_obj = qobject_cast<YourClass*>(QObject::sender());
qDebug() << "finished " << sender_obj->getID();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sender()` is not a clean solution. It breaks modularity which normally is the purpose of using signals and slots.

Documentation says:

> Warning: This function violates the object-oriented principle of modularity.

It is recommended to use [`QSignalMapper`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous solutions, and given you're using Qt 5, another option is to use a lambda that passes the object to your slot:

```
connect(object, &YourClass::finished, [this, object]() {
  fileTransferFinished(object);
});
```